# How can we find an optimal point between minimizing expenses and maximizing revenues?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, optimization, mathematical-optimization

I have this dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from cvxpy import *

data = [{'Month': '2020-01-01', 'Expense':1000, 'Revenue':-50000, 'Building':'Stadium'}, 
       {'Month': '2020-02-01', 'Expense':3000, 'Revenue':40000, 'Building':'Stadium'},
       {'Month': '2020-03-01', 'Expense':7000, 'Revenue':50000, 'Building':'Stadium'}, 
       {'Month': '2020-04-01', 'Expense':3000, 'Revenue':40000, 'Building':'Stadium'},
       {'Month': '2020-01-01', 'Expense':5000, 'Revenue':-6000, 'Building':'Casino'}, 
       {'Month': '2020-02-01', 'Expense':5000, 'Revenue':4000, 'Building':'Casino'},
       {'Month': '2020-03-01', 'Expense':5000, 'Revenue':9000, 'Building':'Casino'},
       {'Month': '2020-04-01', 'Expense':6000, 'Revenue':10000, 'Building':'Casino'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

Now, I am trying to minimize the risk of different investments (in this case Stadiums and Casinos), based on the revenues and expenses of each investment. I am testing this code.

```
# mean return
r = df.pivot_table(index='Month', columns='Building', values='mth_change', aggfunc='mean').mean()


# covariance matrix
C = np.asmatrix(np.cov(r))


# Get symbols
cols = df.Building.unique()
symbols = cols

# Number of variables
n = len(symbols)

# The variables vector
x = Variable(n)

# The minimum return
req_return = 0.02

# The return
ret = r.T*x

# The risk in xT.Q.x format
risk = quad_form(x, C)

# The core problem definition with the Problem class from CVXPY
prob = Problem(Minimize(risk), [sum(x)==1, ret >= req_return, x >= 0])


try:
    prob.solve()
    print ("Optimal portfolio")
    print ("----------------------")
    for s in range(len(symbols)):
       print (" Investment in {} : {}% of the portfolio".format(symbols[s],round(100*x.value[s],2)))
    print ("----------------------")
    print ("Exp ret = {}%".format(round(100*ret.value,2)))
    print ("Expected risk    = {}%".format(round(100*risk.value**0.5,2)))
except:
    print ("Error")
```

When I get to this line of code:

```
risk = quad_form(x, C)
```

I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\RShuell\AppData\Local\Temp\1\ipykernel_11456\2449242452.py", line 1, in <module>
    risk = quad_form(x, C)

  File "C:\Users\RShuell\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\atoms\quad_form.py", line 225, in quad_form
    raise Exception("Invalid dimensions for arguments.")

Exception: Invalid dimensions for arguments.
```

I found the code from this link.

https://www.kdnuggets.com/2019/06/optimization-python-money-risk.html

I am trying to apply that general logic to the data in my specific dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


data = [{'Month': '2020-01-01',  'Revenue':100, 'Building':'Stadium'}, 
        {'Month': '2020-02-01', 'Revenue':400, 'Building':'Stadium'},
        {'Month': '2020-03-01',  'Revenue':500, 'Building':'Stadium'}, 
        {'Month': '2020-04-01',  'Revenue':40, 'Building':'Stadium'},
        {'Month': '2020-01-01',  'Revenue':260, 'Building':'Casino'}, 
        {'Month': '2020-02-01',  'Revenue':400, 'Building':'Casino'},
        {'Month': '2020-03-01',  'Revenue':900, 'Building':'Casino'},
        {'Month': '2020-04-01',  'Revenue':1000, 'Building':'Casino'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df


table = df.pivot(index='Month', columns='Building', values='Revenue')
table.head()


returns = table.pct_change()
mean_returns = returns.mean()

#r = r.fillna(0)
cov_matrix = returns.cov()


# Get symbols
#cols = df.Building.unique()
symbols = table.columns

# Number of variables
n = 2 #len(symbols)

# The variables vector
x = Variable(n)

# The minimum return
req_return = 0.02


#r = r.reset_index()
# The return
ret = mean_returns.T*x

# The risk in xT.Q.x format
risk = quad_form(x, cov_matrix)

# The core problem definition with the Problem class from CVXPY
prob = Problem(Minimize(risk), [sum(x)==1, x >= 0])


try:
    prob.solve()
    print ("Optimal portfolio")
    print ("----------------------")
    for s in range(len(symbols)):
        print (" Investment in {} : {}% of the portfolio".format(symbols[s],round(100*x.value[s],2)))
    print ("----------------------")
    print ("Exp ret = {}%".format(round(100*ret.value,2)))
    print ("Expected risk    = {}%".format(round(100*risk.value**0.5,2)))
except:
    print ("Error")
```

Also, I came across a similar technique to solve the same problem.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from cvxpy import *


data = [{'Month': '2020-01-01', 'Revenue':5000, 'Building':'Stadium'}, 
       {'Month': '2020-02-01',  'Revenue':5500, 'Building':'Stadium'},
       {'Month': '2020-03-01', 'Revenue':6000, 'Building':'Stadium'}, 
       {'Month': '2020-04-01', 'Revenue':6600, 'Building':'Stadium'},
       {'Month': '2020-01-01', 'Revenue':10000, 'Building':'Casino'}, 
       {'Month': '2020-02-01',  'Revenue':11000, 'Building':'Casino'},
       {'Month': '2020-03-01', 'Revenue':12000, 'Building':'Casino'},
       {'Month': '2020-04-01', 'Revenue':13000, 'Building':'Casino'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

thelen = 2

table = df.pivot(index='Month', columns='Building', values='Revenue')
table.head()

returns = table.pct_change()
mean_returns = returns.mean()
cov_matrix = returns.cov()
num_portfolios = 10000
risk_free_rate = 0.0178


def portfolio_annualised_performance(weights, mean_returns, cov_matrix):
    returns = np.sum(mean_returns*weights ) *252
    std = np.sqrt(np.dot(weights.T, np.dot(cov_matrix, weights))) * np.sqrt(252)
    return std, returns
  
def random_portfolios(num_portfolios, mean_returns, cov_matrix, risk_free_rate):
    results = np.zeros((3,num_portfolios))
    weights_record = []
    for i in range(num_portfolios):
        weights = np.random.random(thelen)
        weights /= np.sum(weights)
        weights_record.append(weights)
        portfolio_std_dev, portfolio_return = portfolio_annualised_performance(weights, mean_returns, cov_matrix)
        results[0,i] = portfolio_std_dev
        results[1,i] = portfolio_return
        results[2,i] = (portfolio_return - risk_free_rate) / portfolio_std_dev
    return results, weights_record


def neg_sharpe_ratio(weights, mean_returns, cov_matrix, risk_free_rate):
    p_var, p_ret = portfolio_annualised_performance(weights, mean_returns, cov_matrix)
    return -(p_ret - risk_free_rate) / p_var

def max_sharpe_ratio(mean_returns, cov_matrix, risk_free_rate):
    num_assets = len(mean_returns)
    args = (mean_returns, cov_matrix, risk_free_rate)
    constraints = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: np.sum(x) - 1})
    bound = (0.0,1.0)
    bounds = tuple(bound for asset in range(num_assets))
    result = sco.minimize(neg_sharpe_ratio, num_assets*[1./num_assets,], args=args,
                        method='SLSQP', bounds=bounds, constraints=constraints)
    return result


def portfolio_volatility(weights, mean_returns, cov_matrix):
    return portfolio_annualised_performance(weights, mean_returns, cov_matrix)[0]

def min_variance(mean_returns, cov_matrix):
    num_assets = len(mean_returns)
    args = (mean_returns, cov_matrix)
    constraints = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: np.sum(x) - 1})
    bound = (0.0,1.0)
    bounds = tuple(bound for asset in range(num_assets))
    result = sco.minimize(portfolio_volatility, num_assets*[1./num_assets,], args=args,
                        method='SLSQP', bounds=bounds, constraints=constraints)
    return result


def efficient_return(mean_returns, cov_matrix, target):
    num_assets = len(mean_returns)
    args = (mean_returns, cov_matrix)

    def portfolio_return(weights):
        return portfolio_annualised_performance(weights, mean_returns, cov_matrix)[1]

    constraints = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: portfolio_return(x) - target},
                   {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: np.sum(x) - 1})
    bounds = tuple((0,1) for asset in range(num_assets))
    result = sco.minimize(portfolio_volatility, num_assets*[1./num_assets,], args=args, method='SLSQP', bounds=bounds, constraints=constraints)
    return result


def efficient_frontier(mean_returns, cov_matrix, returns_range):
    efficients = []
    for ret in returns_range:
        efficients.append(efficient_return(mean_returns, cov_matrix, ret))
    return efficients


max_sharpe = max_sharpe_ratio(mean_returns, cov_matrix, risk_free_rate)
sdp, rp = portfolio_annualised_performance(max_sharpe['x'], mean_returns, cov_matrix)
max_sharpe_allocation = pd.DataFrame(max_sharpe.x,index=table.columns,columns=['allocation'])
max_sharpe_allocation.allocation = [round(i*100,2)for i in max_sharpe_allocation.allocation]
max_sharpe_allocation = max_sharpe_allocation.T


min_vol = min_variance(mean_returns, cov_matrix)
sdp_min, rp_min = portfolio_annualised_performance(min_vol['x'], mean_returns, cov_matrix)
min_vol_allocation = pd.DataFrame(min_vol.x,index=table.columns,columns=['allocation'])
min_vol_allocation.allocation = [round(i*100,2)for i in min_vol_allocation.allocation]
min_vol_allocation = min_vol_allocation.T


an_vol = np.std(returns) * np.sqrt(252)
an_rt = mean_returns * 252

for i, txt in enumerate(table.columns):
    print(txt,":","annuaised return",round(an_rt[i],2),", annualised volatility:",round(an_vol[i],2))
print("-"*80)
```